# Calling Angular controller function from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive in `Angular`, which needs to call a function in the controller, passing in some data. The code for the controller and the directive is below. In my directive, when I call `scope.modify(data);`, it calls the function in the controller, but it does not seem to pass the data (it prints the data as *undefined*). Why is this?

My controller has a function, `modify()`, with some logic:

```js
$scope['modify'] = function(data) {
    var obj = $scope['template']();
    console.log(data);
    // ... do stuff with data
}
```

I call it from my directive, which reads in data from a file.

```js
app.directive("modifyBtn", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            modify:"&"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var fileElem = angular.element(element.find("#file_input2"));
            var upload = function() {
                var file = fileElem[0].files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsText(file);
                reader.onload = function(e) {

                    var data = {};

                    // read JSON content from file and store as data

                    console.log(data); // prints correct data
                    scope.modify(data);
                }
            };
            $(fileElem).on("change", upload);
        }
    }
});
```

Finally, here is my directive, view-side, in the `HTML`:

```html
<modify-btn modify="modify()">
    <li class="active">
        <span class="btn creation-btn" ng-click="fileshow = true">
            Upload JSON
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="file" id="file_input2" ng-show="fileshow" />
    </li>
</modify-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is located in the view at the place of usage. With `&` binding you provide an expression that is executed in the scope of controller. And the expression is `modify()`. Notice no arguments. REsult is expected arguemnt in controller function is undefined. Resolution: provide the function name only in template

```
 <modify-btn modify="modify">
```